# how to access a reducer in a submodule

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a complex question that is probably not known by many, but here goes:

I have a submodule project that has it's own store.  I need to map data FROM the parent project TO the store in the submodule project.  How would I access the reducer of the submodule from the parent project in order to update it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your configuration? - are these two separate applications? do they necessarily co-exist?

Comment: They are two separate applications.  They do exist independently of one another.   Project A is the project which has Project B as a submodule.  I need to take data from Project A and map it to a slice in the store of Project B.  But, to do this, I would somehow have to access the store of Project B within Project A, right?  Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: How is this implemented? Is ProjectA embedding ProjectB within an iframe or something of that sort? Code examples are welcome.

Comment: Project B is simply a submodule of project A.  I figured out this problem.  I simply added the action of Project B into a component in Project A (in the components mapDispatchToProps() method).  Then I was able to fire off the action for Project B, which hit the reducer of project B.  So, I can now control the slices of the state in Project B FROM Project A.

Comment: Your submodule project should just export its actions, selectors. Then your other project can use them.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for my project.
The **main-project** and the **sub-module project** each have their own **actions, reducers, types, ...**
Simply import the sub-module project **reducer** into the main-project's **rootReducer**.
In this case, when you call an action from the submodule project, the store of the main project is updated.

**main-project**

```
/*
    rootReducers.js
    you can use alias path name for submodule-project in jsConfig.js
    for exp:
    convert
    'submodules/child-project/store/sell/reducers'
    to
    '@sub-child/store/sell/reducers'
*/
import sell from 'submodules/child-project/store/sell/reducers';
import buy from './buy/reducers';
import fund from './fund/reducers';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    sell,
    buy,
    fund,
});

export default (state, action) => {
    return appReducer(state, action);
};
```